# Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): (hyperref) removing `\<def>-command'

Tags: hyperref, parts, amsbook

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}

\usepackage{amsbooka}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \let\enspace\empty  % this causes the warning for \kern
  \let\noindent\empty % this causes the warning for \indent
}

\title{Hello}
\author{Just Me}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\part{Commutative algebra}

\chapter{Some properties about the radical \author{Me Again}} 

It's like, woah!

\end{document}
```

I get the error:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\<def>-command' on input line 19.

[5] [6]
Chapter 1
./mwe.tex:21: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\MakeUppercase #1->\protect \MakeUppercase  
                                            {#1}
l.21 ...rties about the radical \author{Me Again}}
                                                  
./mwe.tex:21:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on mwe.log.
```

(The lines for `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` suppress some of the hyperref warnings, but not the one above.)

It works if I remove the `amsbooka` package, but I need that for my document (to allow each chapter to have its own author).  But perhaps that is a clue?

Comment: well if you need the package you should perhaps checks its documentation. It clearly says on page one how to use \author in a chapter.

Comment: Welcome at TeX.SX! You should write `\chapter[Some properties about the radical Me Again]{Some properties about the radical \author{Me Again}}`.

Comment: `amsbooka` allows every `\part` to have its own author, not every `\chapter`. That's why the *warning* shows up in line 19 (where you have `\part{...}`).

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried variations on `\part[Commutative algebra]{Commutative algebra}` and `\chapter[Some properties about the radical]{Some properties about the radical \author{Me Again}}` in lines 19, 21 and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @Werner, I don't think it's correct that amsbook only allows every `\part` to have its own author (https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsbooka.pdf): at least according to page 1 of the documentation.  I'm still stuck on this, please help!